# Composer dependecies in Prestashop per module

Tags: php, module, composer-php, prestashop, autoloader

In Prestashop I can write my modules. But I have some code that is framework independent and I want to reuse in other Prestamodules AND in other frameworks I use.

So far so good. My solution was to put an Vendor folder and a composer.json to my Prestamodules to get those libaries  I needed.

Now comes the problem that (offcourse) duplicated namespaces get into conflict. Is there a way around for this or should I do a global vendor folder in the root of Presta (what I want to avoid at any cost, I want to decide when I upgrade a single module or not. So the vendors should be per-module)

Answer (score 0):

Vendors can't be per module if they are executed in the same request. You have to use a central vendor folder for all your dependencies - or you avoid using Composer and try to manage individual dependencies yourself - with the same problem as before: You cannot have two versions of the same class in your code.

Which one gets used? The first that the code encounters, depending on how autoloading is configured. Assume "random" order - it will break your code at the most inconvenient time.